# How to setup an online database for my cross-platform games?

Tags: database, wordpress, haxe, haxeflixel

How to setup database whose data can be obtained by my cross-platform games (Flash on Kongregate, Flash and JavaScript on my WordPress page, Android and iOS) and my WordPress page as well? The data to be saved are gameplay count (total and for each platform) and high scores.

I have no experience about this database thing.
And my games will be made in Haxe.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have a redundant Database, preferably mysql. You can access a mysql database from almost any language / script.

Before you start that Project heads in have a look at what you need. I personally learn the best, if i find myself some example code, take it appart, look at each function if i don't know it already and then i try to find new ways of doing it with the functions provided.

Sqlite Database helper is a great start to create unlimited Databases just to see, how that works, how it looks inside a database, what is a primary key etc. You could even import the whole database to mysql, if you're very happy with it.

Comment: Redundant? Relational maybe? Also, Wordpress requires a relational database anyway. The question is not about technology choice, but rather about the implementation. HTTP API or the likes.

Comment: I actually mean redundant. For the  implementation i would recommend you use http. If you got your own server you can just set up mysql serice within that. It's not to hard. Because if you use an API it's gonna be difficult accessing the database.

Comment: One can set up an API accessed over HTTP, so the last point doesn't make sense. Moreover, that's what modern Web is all about. HTTP APIs can actually be simple.

Comment: Right the way i would do it, if i got my own server i would set up a mysql service. You don't need any apis then, cause you'll connect to your db with a few php lines. You just don't need an api

Comment: "A few PHP lines" can actually be an API :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a database of your choice, it could be mysql or mongodb.
2. Choose a server language of your choice and build a HTTP API to access your db. If you are using Haxe to build the server, you may want to target neko or php if you choose mysql as your db, or nodejs for mongodb. Because Haxe has mysql support for neko & php, and you can download mongodb drivers from npm if you choose mongodb and nodejs.
3. Then, from your games, just use the `Http` class provide in the Haxe standard library to access your Http API to get the data from your db.